# Overriding SASS Mixins

Tags: sass

I'm interested in the capabilities of overriding an existing SASS function with something different. Whether this is something that would just need to be declared earlier, etc -- I'm really interested in being able to override it without having to edit the core files of the application.

To be more specific, overriding the `@media` function. An example of the `@media` function is:

```
$information-phone: "only screen and (max-width : 320px)";

@media #{$information-phone} {
    background: red;
}
```

What I'd like to do do is invalidate the `@media` selector (so I could still use a framework that used them, but the media queries attached to them wouldn't do anything). So running that same function would still "run", but in essence I'd just like to have it not return any output. I've been muddling around for a bit now and haven't found anything about this. Thanks for any/all help!

Comment: `@media` isn't a function, it's a language construct.  There's nothing to override.  If you want to suppress it via Sass, you have to modify (or remove) all instances of the media queries you don't want.

Comment: Gotcha thanks, really appreciate it!